# Post message on Facebook wall

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

I am trying to post a message on Facebook wall through my application. I want to post `"yeehaa, you are on facebook now"`

I am using this code:

```
btnPostToWall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //postToWall();
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("message", "jk");
            try {
                facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
});
```

**The issue is-**

This code opens my facebook wall for me where i write down a message, instead of it i want to post message through my application pragmatically. how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is called the `message` property of the feed. Unfortunately, you cannot add this parameter in case of the [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/), but if you use the Graph API you can add `message`.

Graph API to publish a feed: [**/me/feed**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed/), it has the message parameter, and other parameters used to publish a feed.

Comment: I am already using graph api but got this code from somewhere.

Comment: What's the response/error are you getting now? Post that